# Values of my Array are undefined outside of my function

Tags: arrays, function, actionscript-3

I just started learning AS3 and Flash and I've got a question.
As you can see in the code below, I've created an Array out of Objects which I got from an XML File. Within my function "XMLread" I have no problems tracing, or using the values of the Array or what so ever. My problem is that I want to use the Array outside of the function "XMLread" and not only within. Whenever I try to access the values of "monthParams" outside of the function, it says the array is "undefined". How can I use the Array I created?

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.DataEvent;

var monthParams= new Array;
var month= new Object();
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

myLoader.load(new URLRequest("Parameter.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, XMLread);

var actualMonth= 0;

function XMLread(e:Event){
    var myXML:XML=new XML(e.target.data);
    myXML.ignoreWhitespace=true;

    for (var xmli:int=0; xmli < myXML.monat.length(); xmli++) {
        month.number=myXML.month[xmli].number.text();
        month.namen=myXML.month[xmli].namen.text();
        month.mid=myXML.month[xmli].mid.text();
        month.devi=myXML.month[xmli].devi.text();
        month.incli=myXML.month[xmli].incli.text();
        month.korr=myXML.month[xmli].korr.text();
        monthParams.push(month);
    }
    trace (monthParams[actualMonth].mid);  // works fine
}

trace (monthParams[actualMonth].mid);      // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the xml load is an asynchronous operation, but the code isn't. Which means that first you **start** to load the xml, and immediately after it (on the very last line of code) you try to trace the value. **But** your xml is still **not loaded**. Then, at some point, the xml gets loaded, and `XMLread` is executed, so the trace there prints the now populated array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrey! do you have any suggestions how i could fix this?

Comment: You just need to wait for the function to load. Then "start" whatever you are doing..

Comment: For example, put your final `trace` inside `initialize` function, which will be called **inside** `XMLread`. Then **everything** you need will be called **from** `initialize`.. It's called *initialization flow* - one function starts everything.